# List items to pandas columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have list with 4 urls:

```
['https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-1094197631.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-455156804.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_466214286.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_1475201828.jpg']
```

and I want to build Pandas dataframe which should have `Image_1, Image_2, Image_3`and`Image_4` as column names and URLs as row values.

My code:

```
advert_images = {('Image_1', eval(advert_image_list[0])),
         ('Image_2', eval(advert_image_list[1])),
         ('Image_3', eval(advert_image_list[2])),
         ('Image_4', eval(advert_image_list[3])),
                    }
    adIm_DF = pd.DataFrame(advert_images)
```

is returning error:

> File "", line 1
>       https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-1094197631.jpg
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Evaluation is stuck on "`:`" in URL because it's probably parsing it as dict.

I also need option to itterate over n-number of URLs in list and build coresponding columns with values.
Columns being `Image_(iterator_value)`, row being `URL` value.

Comment: What are you trying to do by using `eval`?

Comment: Because it's breaking string in chars and putting them in separate columns otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URls are stored as a string (as @Tox pointed out) I have no problem with the code:

```
url_list = ['https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-1094197631.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-455156804.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_466214286.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_1475201828.jpg']

im_labels = ['Image_{}'.format(x) for x in np.arange(1, len(url_list) ,1)]

im_df = pd.DataFrame([url_list], columns=im_labels)
```

Comment: Since this has itterator it seems like best answer. Can you adapt np.arange(1,5,1) for itterator if list has undefined number of elements?

Comment: Would this be correct than np.arange(1,len(url_list),1) ?

Comment: Of course, I have adapted the answer to show how you can take the length of the list.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make a string of the url.

```
str((advert_image_list[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the use of `eval`. It is used to run code that is saved in a string. In your example python tries to run the url as code, which will obviously not work. You will not need `eval`.

Try this:

```
advert_image_list = ['https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-1094197631.jpg', 'https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-455156804.jpg', 'https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_466214286.jpg', 'https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_1475201828.jpg']

advert_images = [('Image_1', advert_image_list[0]),
         ('Image_2', advert_image_list[1]),
         ('Image_3', advert_image_list[2]),
         ('Image_4', advert_image_list[3])]

adIm_DF = pd.DataFrame(advert_images).set_index(0).T
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Image1','Image2','Image3','Image4'])
df.loc[0] = ['https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-1094197631.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_-455156804.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_466214286.jpg', 'https://cache.wihaben.at/mmo/6/297/469/806_1475201828.jpg']
```